# Error 75: Error while reading ini file VB6

Tags: file, path, vb6, binary

I am trying to open an ini file in binary mode, I was able to do this successfully.

The problem now is that file can be read from other exe's which I created but fails for one exe with Error number 75: path/Access error.

When I was developing the last exe which is causing an error it was reading the location and file perfectly from my pc. When I moved the exe to the server at which the ini is created it is giving this error. Still when I run that exe from my machine it works.

I am using a dll to read and write the ini. 3 exe's are using that 2 without any problem and one with the issue.

One exe is on the workstation and two are on the server, one exe is reading and writing to file perfectly while the other one gives error 75. The one giving error only reads that file. Not sure when the application from workstation can read it well why not the other? The listed solution does not seems to be helping me as file is not read only. I have given access to the folder where that file exists.

The exe which read and write it well is on the same folder where file exists but the other exe on some other folder

```
AssignVariables:

    NF = FreeFile

    ReadIniValue = ""

    KEY = "[" & LCase$(KEY) & "]"

    Variable = LCase$(Variable)



EnsureFileExists:

    Open INIpath For Binary As NF

    Close NF

    SetAttr INIpath, vbArchive

LoadFile:

    Open INIpath For Input As NF

    While Not EOF(NF)

    Line Input #NF, Temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Let´s see:

1) I think, you can write to an INI file (in the 'Programs' folder) only if your application has admin rights. Most people will tell you that is NOT a good idea. And probably the system Administrator will deny to give you the rights.

2) Why binary access? What´s wrong with text io?

3) What is your goal with the INI file? Would it be possible to use the registry instead?

Comment: there is no particular reason for using binary file, I am using INI to read the path to the server. The idea was: If the server name changes or the server changes we can change that in INI file and read that ini file to access the files required. I also don't know, why one application have rights and other one don't. Both are created by me and I ran them on server with my user account. My user account is under Administrators' group.

Comment: You wrote in your OP that the program throwing the error on write can read the file. So the file exists and therefore it seems to be something with your access rights.

Comment: That is what I am not sure about app1 can read this file and write this file but app2 (on another folder) cannot read it. I just copied that file to the folder of app2 and changed the code to app.path /con.ini and now it worked fine. Just if someone can help what rights should I give to my user account.

Comment: Please tell EXACT which EXE in which DIRECTORY

Comment: I have one exe i.e. Conngen.exe at path \\server\Connection which reads and writes con.ini and another exe i.e. notification.exe at path \\server\Notification the file is at \\server\Connection\ and notifiaction.exe tries to read the file at this location but fails, now I have put the file at location \\server\notification and now notification.exe reads it well

Comment: Ok, it works, it´s fine. But if you have the possibilty to exactly check what your user rights on this directories are you will be sure for future obstacles